# Code working locally but not on host

Tags: php

I am working on a website. I am using an external class to do some image processing. It works perfectly on an  `mamp` server, but on the host I get the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in
/home/a3526504/public_html/post/src/abeautifulsite/SimpleImage.php on line 251
```

The line:

```
$height = $height ?: $width;
```

The server is running php: 5.2

**Solution:
I switched host. I previously used 000webhost, aparently that is dead, and they swapped it out for hostinger. They run php 5.6.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$height = $height ?: $width;
```

this will work only in php 5.3 and above.

Comment: only your host can give an answer to it. but if they don't support atleast 5.3 (i will go for atleast 5.4), then change the host.